# How to notice change in only single item in list in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fetching two lists on my page.

- One list is: `_studentList`.
- Second: `notificationList`.

At first, I am fetching `_studentList`. Then hitting another api for `notificationList` for every 5 seconds, and setting the corresponding notification count like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    _studentList[i].notificationCount = notificationList[i].count;  //Line 1
}
```

Now, I am passing this `_studentList` to three different tabs. Where each tab will display items according to a filter value that I pass to them. Like:

```
ListRenderer(
  students: _studentList,
  filter: 'Class 1',
  ....
)
```

Inside `ListRenderer`:

Constructor, taking two arguments of students and filter as mentioned above and in code:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(students[i].class==filter) {
          ListTile(
            studentInfo: students[i],
          ),
        }
      }
    ]
  )
)
```

Now, inside my ListTile, I am displaying my notification count in a container.

Now, if I use setstate at line 1 (check above), ListRenderer is completely build and entries with no change in notification are also rebuilded. I want that my ListTile corresponding to the change in `students`, only should change. How can I do that?

If I am not clear enough, please tell me to add something more, I will do it.

Comment: Sort it by date created

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing an issue where using `setState` to update the `_studentList` causes the entire `ListRenderer` to rebuild, even when there is no change in the notification count. To optimize the rendering and only update the specific `ListTile` corresponding to the change in the notification count, you can use the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and the `KeepAlive` widget.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

1. First, make sure your `ListTile` widget can properly handle updates and maintain its state. You can achieve this by creating a separate `StatefulWidget` for the `ListTile` contents:

```dart
class StudentTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Student student;

  StudentTile({required this.student});

  @override
  _StudentTileState createState() => _StudentTileState();
}

class _StudentTileState extends State<StudentTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.student.name),
      subtitle: Text('Notification Count: ${widget.student.notificationCount}'),
      // Other ListTile content...
    );
  }
}
```

2. Modify your `ListRenderer` to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `KeepAlive` widget:

```dart
class ListRenderer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Student> students;
  final String filter;

  ListRenderer({required this.students, required this.filter});

  @override
  _ListRendererState createState() => _ListRendererState();
}

class _ListRendererState extends State<ListRenderer>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Ensure the mixin is properly initialized.

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < widget.students.length; i++) {
            if (widget.students[i].class == widget.filter) {
              return KeepAlive(
                child: StudentTile(student: widget.students[i]),
              );
            }
          }
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this setup, the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` and `KeepAlive` widget combination will help maintain the state of individual `StudentTile` widgets and only update the necessary tiles when the notification count changes. This approach should optimize your rendering and prevent unnecessary rebuilds of the entire `ListRenderer`.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT generated. [Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).